# How to open pwa (added to home screen) when an event fired?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Suppose a PWA added to home screen,we have an event, and we want to open the app (progressive web application) when the event fired.

For example in service worker, we check the server (API) every our ,and when the result is OK, PWA open and show some details (or ...).

How we can do it?

And what is the code for open PWA automatically?

Note that we don't want to do this with notifications.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: This is either Too Broad or Unclear, and should be put on hold until it can be clarified and/or narrowed down.